# WPF - How to show controls on Title Bar preserving caption buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, titlebar, window-chrome

i want to make my app similar to Windows 10 Mail App:
[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ1Cj.jpg)

As seen in the image, the left panel is over title bar and even the middle one. But the Caption buttons are preserved.
As my OS is Windows 11 , when I hover mouse over over middle caption button it shows window snap options which proves this are system default caption button and not created

I know title bar is non client area but WPF is a great technology there should be some way to achieve it. I have already seen on many web and mostly found that they set WindowStyle to None and NoResizable or They use WindowChrome and create there own caption buttons, but i want Windows 11's default caption buttons.

One thing I noticed was in Windows Chrome caption buttons are there but just invisible, so if there's anyway to make it visible that would work too.

Or please tell if there is any Nuget Packgage with such Custom Window.

I have tried to create my own caption buttons too :
[My application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKU51.jpg)
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this package and see if it suites you. https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf/wiki/Controls#additional-controls

You may also search for ModernUi or mahapps, they have a lot of styles controls with behaviors already written.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One Problem,i got this error :      ModernWpf.dll cannot be referenced because it uses built-in support for WinRT, which is no longer supported in .NET 5 and higher.  An updated version of the component supporting .NET 5 is needed. For more information, see https://aka.ms/netsdk1149 StylesDemo C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets 1003        All i understood is the thing uses  WinRT and now .net 5 dont support it is there anyother way to use it,       btw thanks for the link it have so many good controls

Comment: The WinRT support is removed from .Net 5 and higher but it works in .Net 3 so i am using it for now but please find a solution i dont want to use lower version everytime.